# Remodeling basement: water, heating and drain pipes running in parallel?

Tags: water, basement, drain, pipe, water-circulating-heating

The piping in our basement is arranged in a way that it is incompatible with our remodeling plans - and the drain pipe also looks quite shoddy, so it needs to go anyway. Also, due to a furnace upgrade, we'd like to rearrange some of the heating related piping too.

**The situation:**
[image: sewer pipe, water connection]

We have a few ideas on how to route the pipes, but would need a few answers in order to be able to decide. (Please disregard the copious amounts of duct tape and various other crazyness present... This is an *improved* situation, a significant step up from the original state.)

**Questions:**

- Can the clean water pipe run below the drain pipe horizontally?
- Can heating pipes be routed below the drain pipe horizontally?
- Would there be any issues if we rearranged the drain pipe to run lower? Would it not increase the probability of clogging?  (e.g. in the level the L profile sticking out from the wall - with the appropriate sloping of course)
- Would it make sense to install a non-return valve in the drain pipe?

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Unfortunately, while all your questions are related to your project, they're really not related to each other and it will be difficult to answer them all in one good answer. Please [edit] your post to break it up into 4 distinct questions, each of which deserves and answer of its own.

Comment: @FreeMan Thank you - I had doubts when sending the question, however as all the questions are centered around the vertical order of said lines with regards to the current design, I decided that they fit the bill better: making 4 of the similar questions scattered around would benefit the future visitors less - someone with a similar setup would most likely ask these questions. At least this is how I felt... What do you think, would a better title work in this case? Thinking about "Arranging parallel runs of water, heating and drain pipes" (Not to mention, separating would mess up the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers:

Can the clean water pipe run below the drain pipe horizontally?

Yes

Can heating pipes be routed below the drain pipe horizontally?

Yes

Would there be any issues if we rearranged the drain pipe to run lower? Would it not increase the probability of clogging? (e.g. in the level the L profile sticking out from the wall - with the appropriate sloping of course)

No. As long as you use the proper radius fittings and maintain a 1/4" in 1' slope, no more, no less. This is especially important for longer horizontal runs. Also, cleanouts are your friend.

Would it make sense to install a non-return valve in the drain pipe?

I assume you mean a check valve. No, those are really only needed for below slab work in basements and sewage pump discharge.